# What are the possible reduced row echelon forms for an $n\times n$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The title makes the question pretty clear, but as an example, for $n=2$ we have 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
 $$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & x\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
 $$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
 $$
Is there a systematic way to list these for general $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a $n \times n$ reduced row echelon form, you satisfy a couple things:

1. The pivot variables (defined as the first nonzero entry in a row from the left) are arranged as follows: if the pivot variable of row $i$ occurs in entry $j$, then the pivot variables (if any) of any row under row $i$ must occur after entry $j$.
2. All completely zero rows are at the bottom of the matrix.
3. Every pivot column (any column with a pivot is a pivot column) must have one and only one nonzero entry.

If you are looking for a systematic way to list all of them for a given $n$, I suggest this strategy:

Start with no zero rows, and increase until you have only zero rows:

1. Choose $n - \text{ (# of zero rows)}$ of the remaining columns to be pivot columns. In those columns, the only nonzero entry must be a $1$ (the pivot). Ensure that condition 1 is satisfied in doing so.
2. Then, for each non pivot column, choose random values for every entry whose row is above the row of the next pivot. If there is no next pivot, fill entries randomly for every entry whose row is above the uppermost zero row.
3. Any unfilled values in the matrix at this point should be filled with a zero.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_i$ be the $i$th standard basis vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$, expressed as a column vector. A reduced row-echelon matrix will contain the columns $e_1, \ldots, e_k$ (for some $k$ between $0$ and $n$), not necessarily next to each other, but in order from left to right. Between $e_i$ and $e_{i+1}$, you can expect an arbitrary column vector in $\operatorname{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_i\}$, which is to say, it has zeros in its $(i+1)$th to $n$th entries, but otherwise arbitrary. Before $e_1$ (or, indeed, if $e_1$ never appears), you can expect $0$ columns.

That's as systematic as I think I can describe it.